# How to make a For loop without using the In keyword in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, keyword

I was just wondering how I could go about using a For loop without using the "in" keyword in Python?

Since the "in" keyword tests to see if a value is in a list, returning True if the value is in the list and False if the value is not in the list, it seems confusing that a For loop uses the In keyword as well when it could just as well use a word like "of" instead.

However, I tried to use a code like this:

```
    for i of range(5):
        print i
```

It returns a syntax error. So I was wondering if there was any way I could use a For loop without also using the In keyword since it is confusing.

Comment: I don't get the down/close votes here.  In what way is this not a real question?  The question is clear, specific, and perfectly answerable ("no, you can't, really.")  It has parallels in other languages where you can modify the syntax and the answer is "yes", and even Python has a few corner cases (`from __future__ import print_function`) with syntactic changes.

Comment: @DSM Agreed, I'm not really sure why this has been closed. I don't feel this is an issue of debate at all. I'm voting reopen.

Comment: @Lattyware: I think some people may have been distracted by the opinion of the OP that it's confusing, but "is there any way I can do X?" is entirely separate from the motivation "because I don't like doing Y".

Comment: @DSM Indeed, unfortunately, once a question has been closed like this, I don't see it getting reopened.

Answer (score 6):

No. There is not, it's a part of the language and can't be changed (without modifying the underlying language implementation).

I would argue that it's not confusing at all, as the syntax reads like English, and parses fine as an LL(1) grammar. It also reduces the number of keywords (which is good as it frees up more words for variable naming).

A lot of languages reuse keywords in different contexts, Python does it with `as` to:

```
import bar as b

with foo() as f:
    ...
```

3.3 does it with `from` too:

```
from foo import bar

def baz(iter):
    yield from iter
```

Even Java does this, `extends` is usually used to give the base class for a class, but it's also used to specify an upper bound on a type for generics.

```
class Foo extends Bar {
    void baz(List<? extends Bar> barList) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that even if this was possible, it would be a bad idea, as it would reduce readability for other Python programmers used to the language as it stands.

Edit:

As other answers have given replacements for the `for` loop using `while` instead, I'll add in the best way of doing  a bad thing:

```
iterable = iter(some_data)
while True:
    try:
        value = next(iterable)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    do_something(value)
```

Comment: I understand now, I didn't realize that homonyms were a part of computer languages too. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @user1990687 No, because in most languages, words can have different meanings based on context.

Comment: @user1990687: in your first sentence (now edited away!), you use the word "mean", which can also signify "average" (cf. median) or "cruel" (cf. Taylor Swift, "One day I'll be living in a big ol' city").  But your sentence wasn't confusing because neither possibility worked grammatically.  Similarly, `for x in a:` and `x in a` aren't confusing in practice, because the `in` is a general membership-in, and the `for` or lack of `for` tells us whether we're looping through or checking containment.

Comment: @user1990687 The cool thing about Python is that it's possible to work out what to do at any given point by looking only one token ahead (an LL(1) grammar) - homonyms are possible because we have enough context to tell the computer what to do. `for x in y:` works because as soon as the computer sees `for`, it knows what should come next in a valid program. In no part of Python do we need to see more than one token ahead of the current one to know what to do (in this case, we only need to see the current token).

Answer (score 1):

No, although you could use a while loop instead:

```
some_list = range(5)
while some_list:
    print some_list.pop()
```

Personally I don't understand why it's unclear though, ever heard of Homonyms? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym

Comment: This isn't the same as it modifies the underlying list (and won't work in 3.x where `range()` doesn't return a list).

Comment: @Lattyware: that is true, I have never claimed equivalency however ;) Alternatively a simple counter would work for something indexable. +1 for your answer btw, it's a better version of a wrong solution :)

Comment: Of course, I'm not saying the answer is bad (no -1s here), just pointing out the difference in how it functions.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that:

```
iter = len(list)
loop = True
while loop:
  if iter == 0:
    loop = False
  else:
    do_something(list[iter])
    iter =- 1
return 0
```

Stupid, but doable ;)

Comment: If you wanted to do this, there are better ways. This is bad in a number of ways (a lot of extra complexity, only works on lists, not iterables, smashing the `iter()` builtin).

Comment: Of course there are, starting with accepting the language structure and syntax and using 'for i in list' ;) However, the question was on how to do it, and here's my quick, dirty and doable example. Never claimed its the best one, actually commented myself on its stupidity.

Comment: Of course, but I thought I'd make mention of *why* it was bad.